# Open set under a function $f$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $A$ be open in $\mathbb{R^n}$; let $f :A \rightarrow \mathbb{R^n}$ be of class $C^r;$ assume $Df(x)$ is non-singular for $x\in A$. Show that even if $f$ is not one-to-one on $A$, the set $B = f(A)$ is open in  $\mathbb{R^n}.$

Thanks for any hint!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem

Comment: @ Tsemo Aristide I don't really see how the theorem can help since it assumes that f is 1-to-1

Comment: @Mathlover No, it does not.

Comment: Sorry, I can not see how to show the whole set $f(A)=B$ is open.

Comment: Inverse function theorem tells you that for each $x \in A$ there is open set $U_x$ containing $x$ such that $U_x \subset A$ and $f(U_x)$ is open.$A$ is the union of all these open sets so $f(A)$ is the union of the open sets $f(U_x)$. Hence $f(A)$ is open.